# ExpandableListView no se expande

Tags: java, android, android-studio

vereis os comento mi problema, tengo un dialogo que muestra varios elementos, entre ellos un ExpandableListView, el diseño esta personalizado de forma que sale un checkbox y el texto padre, el problema viene cuando pulso cualquier padre del expandable list view, este no se expande, he probado varias cosas como hacer que se expanda el grupo en el ongroupclicklistener pero no encuentro nada, os dejo algo de codigo:

El adaptador:

```
public class GModPreciosAdapterFinal extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Context mContext;

//private ArrayList<Family> mlistDataHeader; // header titles
private ArrayList<String> mlistDataHeader; // header titles

// child data in format of header title, child title
private HashMap<String, ArrayList<Article>> mlistDataChild;
//private HashMap<Family, ArrayList<Article>> mlistDataChild;
//private HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> mlistDataChild;


public GModPreciosAdapterFinal(Context mContext, ArrayList<String> mlistDataHeader, HashMap<String, ArrayList<Article>> mlistDataChild) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mlistDataHeader = mlistDataHeader;
    this.mlistDataChild = mlistDataChild;
}

@Override
public Article getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    //public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return this.mlistDataChild.get(this.mlistDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    String cabecera = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if(convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_mprecio_exp_list_fam, parent, false);
    }
    TextView labelListaCabecera = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.familia_lista);
    CheckBox checkboxFam = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkboxlista);
    labelListaCabecera.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    labelListaCabecera.setText(cabecera);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    if (this.mlistDataChild.get(this.mlistDataHeader.get(groupPosition)) == null){
        return 0;
    }

    return this.mlistDataChild.get(this.mlistDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).size();
}

@Override
//public Family getGroup(int groupPosition) {
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return this.mlistDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return this.mlistDataHeader.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String cabecera = getGroup(groupPosition).toString();
    if(convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_mprecio_exp_list_fam, parent, false);
    }
    TextView labelListaCabecera = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.familia_lista);
    CheckBox checkboxFam = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkboxlista);
    labelListaCabecera.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    labelListaCabecera.setText(cabecera);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public void registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
    super.registerDataSetObserver(observer);
}
```

El codigo de la lista expandible en el dialogo:

```
ArrayList listaFamilias = Utility.dbHelper.getAllFamilies();
    Log.i("","Familias "+listaFamilias);
    HashMap<String, ArrayList<Article>>[] listaArt = new HashMap[1];
    listaArt[0] = Utility.dbHelper.getHashMapStringWithNoGroups();
    Log.i("","Familias "+listaArt);
    Log.i("","Familias "+listaArt[0]);

    GModPreciosAdapterFinal[] adaptr = new GModPreciosAdapterFinal[1];
    adaptr[0] = new GModPreciosAdapterFinal(getActivity(),listaFamilias,listaArt[0]);
    //GModPreciosAdapterFinal adapter = new GModPreciosAdapterFinal(getActivity(),listaFamilias, listaArt[0]);
    listaExp.setAdapter(adaptr[0]);
    listaExp.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {
            listaExp.expandGroup(groupPosition);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Alguien se le ocurre que puede estar pasando?

un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asegura primeramente que tu `ExpandableListView` NO tenga definida la propiedad:

```
android:clickable="true"
```

**Para solucionar el problema, en el listener `OnGroupClickListener` define un valor de retorno "`false`" para indicar que deseas expander el grupo.**

```
listaExp.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {
            listaExp.expandGroup(groupPosition);
            //return true;
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por contestar, he probado lo que me has comentado y no se abria al pulsar en el parent, lo que he echo ha sido añadir un boton al diseño que abra los child y me ha funcionado, un saludo